# Почему не получается задать ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я пишу:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemHeaderTemplate">
  <DataTemplate.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
  </DataTemplate.Resources>
  <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" ToolTip="{Binding}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Name="CLOSE"
            Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" 
            Width="15" 
            Height="15" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Template="{StaticResource CloseButtonTemplate}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem},
            Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
  </Grid>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="CLOSE" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Trigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

<TabControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemHeaderTemplate}">
  <TabControl.Items>
    <TabItem Header="This is test tab item with longer name." Width="100"/>
    <TabItem Header="Short name" Width="100"/>
  </TabControl.Items>
</TabControl>
```

Но шаблон не применяется! В чем проблема? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы задаете `Items` или `ItemsSource` с элементами типа `TabItem`, это работать не будет, потому что `TabControl` формирует эти самые `TabItem'ы` на основе заданного `ItemTemplate'а`. Поскольку у вас `TabItem'ы` уже сформированы, то `TabControl` просто добавит их в коллекцию табов. Если вы хотите поменять темплейт самой табы, то нужно подсунуть ему какой-нибудь другой класс и на основе него формировать темплейт. Если вам нужно поменять контент самой табы (*то, что находится внутри*) - используйте `TabControl.ContentTemplate`.

В качестве примера, я немного переписал ваш код.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemHeaderTemplate">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" ToolTip="{Binding}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                <Button Name="CLOSE"
        Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"
        Width="15" 
        Height="15" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem},
        Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="CLOSE" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TabControl
        x:Name="TabControl"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemHeaderTemplate}"
    >
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Возможно, реализация `ICommand` будет лишняя, но всё же, я решил вставить её, для наглядности.

**CODE**

```
public class Command : ICommand {
    public Command(Action<object> action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    readonly Action<object> action;

    EventHandler canExecuteChanged;
    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged {
        add { canExecuteChanged += value; }
        remove { canExecuteChanged -= value; }
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return true;
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter) {
        action(parameter);
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel {
    public ItemViewModel(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    readonly int id;
    public int ID { get { return id; } }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }
}

public class Content {
    public Content(ICommand closeCommand) {
        items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>() {
            new ItemViewModel(0) {
                Header = "This is test tab item with longer name.",
                CloseCommand = closeCommand
            },
            new ItemViewModel(1) {
                Header = "Short name",
                CloseCommand = closeCommand
            }
        };
    }

    readonly IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> items;
    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get { return items; } }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var closeCommand = new Command(CloseTab);
        DataContext = new Content(closeCommand);
    }

    void CloseTab(object tabID) {
        if(tabID == null)
            return;
        var id = (int)tabID;
        var items = (ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>)TabControl.ItemsSource;
        items.Remove(items.First(x => x.ID == id));
    }
}
```

`ObservableCollection` использована для того, чтобы послать нотификации об изменении этой коллекции для корректного удаления `TabItem'а`.

*P.S: Можно было бы реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, но в данной ситуации достаточно и `ObservableCollection`*

Comment: Точно спасибо, это я вкладки задал просто для теста, я не ожидал что на них шаблон не распространится.